# How to set background image to UINavigationbar that set in storyboard

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

I'm using Xcode 4.4.1 and iOS 5.

I have set the Navigation bar for several viewcontrollers using the storyboard.Now I want to set a background image for all those navigationbars.

so in my AppDelegate.m I put this,

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
UIImage *naviImg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBackgroundImage:naviImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

But it not changes any thing in any Viewcontroller's navigationbar.
Can any one tell me how to do that, I'm very new to iOS development.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,set the IBOutlet for the navigation bar in the `viewController.h` where you want to change the image.

```
IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navigationBar;
```

Then in viewDidLoad write this code,

```
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"wall.jpg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Home.m:31:6: No visible @interface for 'UINavigationItem' declares the selector 'setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:' This error give me

Comment: UINavigationItem?????
Your problem is about UINavigationBar right?
You just declare an IBOutlet of UINavigationBar in interface file and  then write the code in viewDidLoad as i already told.
i am not clear why this error is coming.
Can you find out exactly at what line the error is coming.